# Add animated background to events on fullcalendar 4.2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'd like to add animated striped background to all events in fullcalendar 4.2.0, like bootstrap progress bars.

I tried with:

```
eventSourceSuccess: function(){

    $(".fc-content").addClass("progress-bar");
    $(".fc-content").addClass("progress-bar-striped");
    $(".fc-content").addClass("active");

}
```

But nothing appened.

This is my fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/g0xcm7ja/11/

Comment: I know you fixed this below, and maybe you realised this already, but it's worth noting that this happens because the eventSourceSuccess event occurs after the events have been downloaded, but before they have been rendered onto the calendar. Therefore at that moment `$(".fc-content")` does not match anything - because there are not any event elements with this class in the page yet.

Answer (score 2):

Found solution:

```
  eventRender: function (info) {
     $(info.el).addClass("progress-bar-fc");
     $(info.el).addClass("progress-bar-striped");
  }
```

CSS:

```
    .progress-bar-fc {
    -webkit-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
    animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
    }
```